# TableViewの軽量化

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, xcode7

## 現状

Cellの生成の際に毎回AXRatingViewを呼び出し、
レーティングを表示しているためなのか、
上下にスクロールを繰り返しているとメモリ消費量が多くなり動作が重くなってしまいます。

## どうしたいのか

できるだけ上下させても動作を軽くしたいのですが、
どのように書き換えればよろしいでしょうか、ご教授願います。

## Source

```
import UIKit
import AXRatingView

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(table: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(table: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let label1 = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label1.text = "あいうえお\nかきくけこ\nさしすせそ\nたちつてと"
        star(cell)

        return cell
    }

    func star(cell: UITableViewCell) {

        let usersRating: AXRatingView = AXRatingView(frame: CGRectZero)
        usersRating.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        usersRating.value = 1.0
        usersRating.userInteractionEnabled = false
        usersRating.sizeToFit()
        cell.contentView.addSubview(usersRating)

    }

}
```

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/37946　マルチポスト

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AXRatingView`を毎回生成しているため、多重に表示されています。例えば`Tag`を設定するなどして、再利用すると良いかと思います。

```
import UIKit
import AXRatingView

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let kUserRatingViewTag: Int = 37564

    func tableView(table: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(table: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let label1 = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label1.text = "あいうえお\nかきくけこ\nさしすせそ\nたちつてと"
        if let usersRating = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(kUserRatingViewTag) as? AXRatingView {
            usersRating.value = 1.0;
        } else {
            star(cell)
        }
        return cell
    }

    func star(cell: UITableViewCell) {

        let usersRating: AXRatingView = AXRatingView(frame: CGRectZero)
        usersRating.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        usersRating.value = 1.0
        usersRating.userInteractionEnabled = false
        usersRating.sizeToFit()
        usersRating.tag = kUserRatingViewTag
        cell.contentView.addSubview(usersRating)
    }
}
```

独自の`UITableViewCell`を作るのがより良いと思います。